# On the calculation of chi-square statistics for variables following a multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, summation, random-variables

## Setup

$X=(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_k) \sim M_N(n; p_1, \cdots, p_k),\ n = N_1+ \cdots +N_k$ and
$$
\chi^2 := \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(X_i - np_i)^2}{np_i}
$$

## Fact

$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[(X_i - np_i)^4]}{(np_i)^2} = 3\left(1-\frac{2}{n} \right) (1-2p_i+p_i^2) + \frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{p_i}-1 \right)
$$
and
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}[(X_i - np_i)^2(X_j -np_j)^2]}{(np_i)(np_j)} = \left(1-\frac{2}{n} \right) (1-p_i-p_j) + 3\left( 1-\frac{2}{n} \right) p_i p_j + \frac{1}{n}
$$

## What I know

$$
(\chi^2)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(X_i - np_i)^4}{(np_i)^2} + \sum_{i\neq j}^k \frac{(X_i - np_i)^2 (X_j - np_j)^2}{(np_i)(np_j)},
$$

$$
\mathbb{E}[(\chi^2)^2] = 3\left(1-\frac{2}{n} \right) \sum_{i=1}^k (1-2p_i+p_i^2) + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^k \left( \frac{1}{p_i}-1 \right) + \left(1-\frac{2}{n} \right) \sum_{i\neq j}^k (1-p_i-p_j) + 3\left( 1-\frac{2}{n} \right) \sum_{i\neq j}^k p_i p_j + \sum_{i\neq j}^k \frac{1}{n}
$$

## Qustion

I want to find the second moment $\mathbb{E}[(\chi^2)^2]$.
I don't understand the calculation of $\sum_{i=1}^k p_i^2$ and $\sum_{i\neq j}^k p_i p_j\ (i\neq j)$ that comes up in this case.

I can use $p_1 + \cdots + p_k = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but can you add $\sum_{i=1}^kp_i^2$ and $\sum_{i\neq j}p_i p_j$ to get $(\sum_{i=1}^kp_i)^2 = 1^2=1$?